# Magento 2 Class PayMongo\Payments\Controller\Payment\Start\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2.4.5

I have installed the Paymongo module. https://marketplace.magento.com/cyndertech-paymongo-gateway.html
but when I place an order with PayMongo - Credit Card so getting an error.

```
  1 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class PayMongo\Payments\Controller\Payment\Start\Interceptor does not exist Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class PayMongo\Payments\Controller\Payment\Start\Interceptor does not exist <pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54] #2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below command.

```
rm -rf generated/code/ var/page_cache/ var/cache/ 
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```